# Developer Exception page middle ware is not working in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: .net

My goal is to get development environment error messages in asp.net core projects. But I get status code pages instead. I created a new .net core 3.1 project with MVC. I confirmed that development environment is set to Development by going to Properties>Debug. Without changing Visula Studio 2019 codes I pressed F5 and entered a random path, instead of developer page I receive status code 404.
I have tried using app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects() middle-ware to return a view. but I need to see the exception error messages. Here is the configure method. I confirmed that this code runs `{app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {

                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Comment: Poor routing alone should not cause an exception in your application. If you want to see the developer exception page, cause an exception while your web browser is actively open to your application.